# VSCode не может найти Main-class после установки Maven-зависимости

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

Такая дилемма - после установки зависимости(jsoup-1.14.3) через Maven в VSCode, и при попытке запуска VSCode выдает ошибку, что не может загрузить класс Main(в котором точка входа). Попробовал установить другие зависимости, всё гладко. Есть ли какие-нибудь предложения?

Использую JavaSE-17, Maven-3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

Спустя час копаний, я решил изменить код лаунчера расширения Java Debugger находящийся по адресу `C:\Users\{user}\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.36.0\scripts\launcher.bat` на вот этот:

```
@echo off

REM Change code page to UTF-8 for better compatibility.
@chcp.com 65001 > NUL 

REM Execute real command passed by args

for %%a in (%*) do set /a cnt+=1

if %cnt%==6 ( goto argfile ) else ( goto without_argfile )

:argfile
set java=%1

set pathTo=%5
set pathTo=%pathTo:@=%

set /p cp=<%pathTo%

set file=%6

%java% %cp% %file%
exit

:without_argfile
%*
```